# ZombieJS - How do I call JavaScript functions or check JavaScript values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zombie.js

```
var Browser = require("zombie");

// Load the page from localhost
browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("http://localhost:3000/", function () {

  // Let's say the page has window.jQuery
  // How do I access it?

});
```

So, How do I access the window and the javascript variables? I want to check if my script tracks 'clicks' correctly. I want to do something like `expect(browser.document.window.myScript.click_counter).toBe 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you stored your variable.
If you stored it in a global object `myScript`, use:

```
browser.window.myScript.click_counter
```

If you have something like `myScript.click_counter = 5; document.myScript = { ... }` , use:

```
browser.document.myScript.click_counter
```

Comment: The script loads asynchronously. How can I detect when it's loaded? that's why I wasn't able to access it.

Comment: You could use the `browser.wait` API described here: https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/master/doc/API.md

Comment: sadly, it doesn't seem to work. could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 4):

I got it *working* with the following... having set the maxWait options

```
var opts = {
    debug: false
    , runScripts: true
    , maxWait: 10
    , waitFor: 10000
};

this.browser = new Browser(opts);

this.browser.visit(url, callback);

this.browser.wait(function(window) {
    console.log('wait...');

    return window.document.querySelector("#objectid");
}, function(e, browser) {
    console.log('wait complete ', e) ;
});
```

However the second `callback` method never fires and the `querySelector` call always fails. I don't think the `window.document` DOM is updated after the javascript injection has fired.

*[edit]*

I removed the callback from `browser.visit()` to make the wait callback fire.

```
this.browser.visit(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to crank maxWait up to 100. Which is strange, because, presuming that's in ms, that's short, but in seconds, its insanely long.  Its not really clear what maxWait does, but it seemed to make a difference.  Unfortunately, I'm using Behat/Mink with Zombie.js and I had to hack the source of the Mink driver to make it work, which is disappointing because I can't update that driver now without problems...